# sort in jinja2 when attribute is not available

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a set of articles (using [pelican](https://github.com/getpelican) for generating static sites) which includes a category called hotels. I'd like to sort these hotels. The problem is that only the hotels have an attribute called 'city' while the other articles do not and this obviously leads to the following error:

```
Caught exception "'pelican.contents.Article object' has no attribute 'city'".
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
{% for article in articles|sort(attribute='city') %}
{% if article.category == 'hotels' %}
    <a href="hotels/{{ article.slug }}.html">
    <p>{{ article.title }}</p>
    </a>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to check to see if the attribute exists and provide some default value so that it does not cause an error?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to move your `if` statement into your `for` loop as a filter:

```
for article in articles if article.category == 'hotels' | sort(attribute='city')
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint Sean.. I got this when I used your suggestion: CRITICAL: 'str object' has no attribute 'city'. Seems like the sort is applied to all objects in articles.

Comment: This solution does not work (anymore?): the `|sort()` filter is applied to the `'hotels'` string. I couldn't find a way to make filters work after `for-if`, so I solved a similar issue using selectattr filter: `for article in articles | selectattr('category', 'equalto', 'hotels') | sort(attribute='city')`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show only entries that have a `'city'` attribute, and have that list sorted by `'city'`, do:

```
for article in articles|selectattr("city")|sort(attribute="city")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over **only** the hotels, see [Sean Vieira's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15595252/520779). If you want to iterate over **all** articles, but have the hotels sorted while the rest are in arbitrary order, you can do it by using [macros](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#macros):

```
{% macro my_macro(article) %}
    ...
{% endmacro %}

{% for a in articles if a.category == 'hotels' | sort(attribute='city') %}
    {{ my_macro(a) }}
{% endfor %}

{% for a in articles if a.category != 'hotels' %}
    {{ my_macro(a) }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will include everything you defined in `my_macro` first for each hotel, in the desired order, then for each article that is not a hotel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get "CRITICAL: 'str object' has no attribute 'city'." when I do this.. same as what I listed for Sean Vieira's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page when was looking for a similar solution. 
Eventually, I solved it a bit differently and it might be helpful for someone else.

In one of my templates for Pelican I added statistics collected by 'post_stats' plugin about approximate time to read. It looked like

```
~{{ article.stats['read_mins']|default("0") }} min read
```

But if the plugin is not loaded then the 'article' object doesn't have the 'stats' attribute and rendering fails.

Jinja has the builtin test for testing if a variable is defined.
So, I came up with this solution

```
~{{ article.stats['read_mins'] if article.stats is defined else "0" }} min read
```